# How to generate java source of JPA Entity?

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea

I found this amazing autocomplete function in IDE when I was watching youtube video "[From Zero to Hero with SpringBoot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aA4tfBGY6jY&t=72s)", the time is at 9:00.
Is there a idea plugin or something else? Here is the picture in the video.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtyDB.png)

I tried to google this function ,but cannot find any answers.

Comment: I don't know about anybody else, but I can't read what's written in the image that you posted. Is that popup, that is circled in red, the _amazing autocomplete function_ that you are referring to?

Comment: Yes, is the image not clear? Or could you see the video at 9:00m

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have updated the screenshot to make it clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the picture, it's just a possible word list, not anything about generating a JPA entity.

You can use the free plugin JPA Buddy to do so: https://jpa-buddy.com/guides/generate-or-synchronize-jpa-hibernate-entities

Comment: Got it！Thanks a lot！